# What is the best way to cache objects at phone - iOS

Tags: ios, object, caching, ios8

Does anyone can recommend what is the best way to cache the objects at phone for offline display propose?

Thanks

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951334/store-data-locally-ios

Answer (score 0):

u can use database (ex Realm https://realm.io/)